# UITableView iOS 8 Xcode 6.0.1 Unrecognised Selector Send To Instance

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa, ios8

I have a simple UITableView. Everything works fine on iOS 7 but on iOS 8 not. Basically I have a custom UITableViewCell which contains text labels, buttons, images. When I press the button inside the tableview cell I got error. Here is the code:

```
-(IBAction)addToFavorites:(id)sender {

    UIButton *editButton = (UIButton*)sender;
    GetMoreTableViewCell *editCell = (GetMoreTableViewCell*)[[[editButton superview] superview] superview];
    int editIndex = (int)[[_chapters indexPathForCell:editCell] row];

    [self readTopScorePlist];

    if([[[[_data valueForKey:key] valueForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",editIndex]] valueForKey:@"isDefault"] boolValue] == YES) {
        [editCell.addButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"fav_0.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [self saveToPlist:NO sender:sender];
        NSLog(@"NEW %@",[[[_data valueForKey:key] valueForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",editIndex]] valueForKey:@"isDefault"]);
    }
    else {
        [editCell.addButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"fav_1.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [self saveToPlist:YES sender:sender];
        NSLog(@"NEW %@",[[[_data valueForKey:key] valueForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",editIndex]] valueForKey:@"isDefault"]);
    }
}
```

The method is called however I am getting exception here:`[editCell.addButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"fav_0.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];`

And the expection that I am getting is:

```
2014-09-22 10:08:28.223 HandyHoch[657:252982] -[UITableViewWrapperView addButton]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x17e9fd80
```

I am guessing that addButton cannot be finded, but who should I do that in iOS 8? Thanks in advance.

```
The UITableViewCell custom class: 

@implementation GetMoreTableViewCell

@synthesize  ttitle, cellImage, cellBackground, changeButton, deleteButton,addButton;

-(id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if(self) {

        ttitle.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        ttitle.numberOfLines = 30;
        ttitle.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByCharWrapping;
        ttitle.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
        [self.contentView addSubview:ttitle];
        [self.contentView addSubview:addButton];
        [self setAutoresizesSubviews:YES];

    }
    return self;
}

@end
```

Comment: Please post the code from your `GetMoreTableViewCell` class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the view hierarchy changed in iOS 8, so `(GetMoreTableViewCell*)[[[editButton superview] superview] superview];` returns different view. Easiest solution would be change the number of superview calls for iOS 8. The more reliable solution would be connect target to `GetMoreTableViewCell`.